"Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly"? When before it worked good and still work good on a pc friend
I have just re-installed XAMPP with the same version of a friend where it work for him but for my both pc when I try to start my Apache server in the XAMPP Control Panel, I now get the following errors:
    17:53:09  [main]    Initializing Control Panel
17:53:09  [main]    Windows Version:  Home  64-bit
17:53:09  [main]    XAMPP Version: 8.0.28
17:53:09  [main]    Control Panel Version: 3.3.0  [ Compiled: Apr 6th 2021 ]
17:53:09  [main]    You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for
17:53:09  [main]    most application stuff but whenever you do something with services
17:53:09  [main]    there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think 
17:53:09  [main]    about running this application with administrator rights!
17:53:09  [main]    XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
17:53:09  [main]    Checking for prerequisites
17:53:09  [main]    All prerequisites found
17:53:09  [main]    Initializing Modules
17:53:09  [main]    Starting Check-Timer
17:53:09  [main]    Control Panel Ready
17:53:13  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache app...
17:53:13  [Apache]  Status change detected: running
17:53:13  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
17:53:13  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
17:53:13  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
17:53:13  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
17:53:13  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
17:53:13  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
17:53:13  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
17:53:13  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
17:55:33  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache app...
17:55:33  [Apache]  Status change detected: running
17:55:33  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
17:55:33  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
17:55:33  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
17:55:33  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
17:55:33  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
17:55:33  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
17:55:33  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
17:55:33  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums

How do I solve this please ?
I already try to change the port to 8080 and 4433

Check windows event viewer and see what cause the error

I unstall and install a new version again and it is good I guess I got a problem with my Apache version ...
